# How to Close a program using python?

Tags: python

Is there a way that python can close a windows application (example: Firefox) ?

I know how to start an app, but now I need to know how to close one.

Comment: What kind of application do you mean?  A python application?  An external one?

Comment: @Stedy Firefox, i'm using python to open a web page every 2 hours and i need to close that page after 5 minutes.

Comment: @user514584: why are you using an external program to open a webpage instead of using urllib?

Comment: @Wooble I did not know about urllib and the page that i'm opening will need flash player.

Comment: @acrs To close an app by name, refer my code in the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/70849062/12862934

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
# I have used subprocess comands for a while
# this program will try to close a firefox window every ten secounds

import subprocess
import time

# creating a forever loop
while 1 :
    subprocess.call("TASKKILL /F /IM firefox.exe", shell=True)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: This works but I get __Access denied__. I am using windows.

Comment: you're getting access denied because you're on a server and other people are using firefox. You can only kill _your_ instances

Comment: @ellockie is there a way I can tell it to task kill all applications that are not py.launcher?

Comment: @HGaming By using a `regex`, you need to specify all files except the `py.launcher`

Comment: I am getting an : taskkill is not recognised as a batch or an internal command

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `Popen`, you should be able to terminate the app using either `send_signal(SIGTERM)` or `terminate()`.

[See docs here.](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate)

Answer (score 7):

in windows you could use `taskkill` within `subprocess.call`:

```
subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","firefox.exe"])
```

`/F` forces process termination. Omitting it only asks firefox to close, which can work if the app is responsive.

Cleaner/more portable solution with `psutil` (well, for Linux you have to drop the `.exe` part or use `.startwith("firefox")`:

```
import psutil,os
for pid in (process.pid for process in psutil.process_iter() if process.name()=="firefox.exe"):
    os.kill(pid)
```

that will kill all processes named `firefox.exe`

By the way `os.kill(pid)` is "overkill" (no pun intended). `process` has a `kill()` method, so:

```
for process in (process for process in psutil.process_iter() if process.name()=="firefox.exe"):
    process.kill()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want probably use `os.kill` http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill

Answer (score 1):

In order to kill a python tk window named MyappWindow under MS Windows:

```
from os import system
system('taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq MyappWindow" ')
```

stars maybe used as wildcard:

```
from os import system 
system('taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq MyappWind*" ')
```

Please, refer to  "taskkill /?" for additional options.

Answer (score 1):

An app(a running process) can be closed by it's name using it's PID(Process ID) and by using `psutil` module. Install it in cmd using the command:

> `pip install psutil`

After installing, run the code given below in any .py file:

```
import psutil
def close_app(app_name):
    running_apps=psutil.process_iter(['pid','name']) #returns names of running processes
    found=False
    for app in running_apps:
        sys_app=app.info.get('name').split('.')[0].lower()

        if sys_app in app_name.split() or app_name in sys_app:
            pid=app.info.get('pid') #returns PID of the given app if found running
            
            try: #deleting the app if asked app is running.(It raises error for some windows apps)
                app_pid = psutil.Process(pid)
                app_pid.terminate()
                found=True
            except: pass
            
        else: pass
    if not found:
        print(app_name+" not found running")
    else:
        print(app_name+'('+sys_app+')'+' closed')

close_app('chrome')
```

After running the code above you may see the following output if google chrome was running:

```
>>> chrome(xyz) closed
```

Feel free to comment in case of any error

Answer (score 0):

On OS X:

1. Create a shell script and put:

```
killall Application
```

Replace Application with a running app of your choice.

In the same directory as this shell script, make a python file.
In the python file, put these two lines of code:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen('sh shell.sh', shell=True)
```

Replace `shell.sh` with the name of your created shell script.

Comment: Is it possible to "gently" kill the app? so for example I want to kill excel but I still want it to ask me to save the sheet?

Comment: @JoanArau I'm not really sure. Killing an app immediately terminates the process, so you shouldn't use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
from AppOpener import close
close("whatsapp") 
close("telegram, brave") 
close("name of ur application")
```

#pip install AppOpener