# How do I stop a running file using python? (linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

In my code I have added this:

```
os.system("./usr/bin/google-chrome")
```

However, I want it to shut off google chrome after a certain amount of time. I have tried this:

```
os.system("killall -15 chrome")
```

The problem I am having right now is that it will not continue unless I close google chrome manually.

Comment: This might help you a bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625524/how-to-close-a-program-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pkill`:

```
os.system('pkill chrome')
```

In windows:

```
os.system(r'taskkill /im chrome.exe /f')
```

Comment: I was able to do this, but I meant that the python code would not move on to the part where it kills the task until I closed google chrome.