# Unable to prevent program to print a Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I took a piece of code from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10457565/13882705
which is

```
# I have used os comands for a while
# this program will try to close a firefox window every ten secounds

import os
import time

# creating a forever loop
while 1 :
    os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM firefox.exe")
    time.sleep(10)
```

It will terminate a process if it is running using OS module
But if the program did not find the app we mentioned then it prints
`ERROR: The process "firefox.exe" not found.`

Is there a way to make the program just print application not found once and wait until the program is rerunned?

It is fine even if it just prints "Application Not found"

Comment: @Guimoute `os.system` does not throw exceptions on non-zero exit codes, so this code wouldn't work.

Comment: What is the appropriate error?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead of `os.system` so you have more control:

```py
import subprocess
import time

while True:
    proc = subprocess.run(["TASKKILL", "/F", "/IM", "firefox.exe"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if proc.returncode != 0:
        print("Application not found.")
        break # since application isn't here we just exit
    time.sleep(10)
```