# How to close a specific application on windows using python?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm self-studying python so I'm very inexperienced so I hope you guys can help
The specific problem is:
I'm building a voice communication virtual assistant, I have managed to open the application by voice, but can't write the code to close a running application with a specific name.
I tried using the command
`send_keys('%{F4}')`
and doesn't seem to get the desired result
So is there any other way?

```
    elif "discord" in you:
    app =  application.Application()
    app.start("C://Users//admin//AppData//Local//Discord//Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe")
    robot_brain = "runing Discord"
elif you == " exit discord":
    send_keys('%{F4}') # close an active window with Alt+F4
    robot_brain = " exit discord"
```

Comment: Regarding `update.exe`... No GUI commands should be automated with built-in module `subprocess`. pywinauto is for GUI automation only, i.e. for complicated cases. Command line automation is much easier, even batch script or PowerShell could be enough in many cases. So even Python may be not necessary.

Comment: And at the second hand, `app.close(soft=False)` could be used, or with `soft=True` if you don't want hard termination.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill).

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(['taskkill', '/f', '/im', 'program_name.exe'])
assert proc.wait() == 0
```

Comment: Also there is option `/T` for hard termination. `taskkill` is really the best for such purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, im not too sure what the app is (in your code) but you can use the os module to start files and to start a exe and to exit it
example**

```
import os
os.system("C:/Users/username/Downloads/main.exe")
```

this starts the file *(use startfile instead of system if you want to open like a txt or anything not exe file)*

their is alot of way to close it heres some usefull links

[How to Close a program using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625524/how-to-close-a-program-using-python)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill